# How to set DATE in object, JSP SERVLET

Tags: jsp, date, servlets, illegalargumentexception

I've had this time for about quite sometime now and i've run out of resources for research.

In my servlet, i have this code:

```
    comment.setDateadded(Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("date")));
```

The code basically gets data from a JSP page then is set as one of the object's values.

The problem is:

When the servlet is called and run returns this error:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[add_comment]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet add_comment threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:117)
    at Controller.Leader.add_comment.processRequest(add_comment.java:50)
    at Controller.Leader.add_comment.doPost(add_comment.java:96)
```

What i've tried:
I'm not sure what the problem is anymore. I imported

```
import java.sql.Date;
```

in the servlet ofor the line to work. I've also tried manually putting in the date instead of putting automatically the current date but it still does not work. Ive tried yyyy/mm/dd format and the yyyy-mm-dd but it still wont work.

For those who will comment, thank you very much! If you need more details, please post.

Comment: You should not be using `java.sql.Date` in your servlet classes. You should be using this in your DAO classes only.

Answer (score 2):

For most of the scenario you need `java.util.Date` and not `java.sql.Date`

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) of `java.sql.Date`

> Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if the date given is not in the JDBC date escape format (yyyy-mm-dd)

which means date coming from jsp is not in the form of `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

If you are going to use java.sql.Date object then format the incoming date to `yyyy-mm-dd` format before using `valueOf` API.

For conversion you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to format your incoming value to `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Edit:

Even better instead of using Date object you should [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for most of the operation.

Edit:

As per comments:

Assuming my Incoming date from JSP is dd-MMM-yyyy format.

```
try {
    String date = "25-Apr-2012";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    date = dateFormat.format(parsedDate);
    System.out.println(date);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date);
    System.out.println(sqlDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the comment. I've made the format yyyy-mm-dd however it still has the same error. 

I will check out the Calendar you're mentioning. Thank you very much! If you've got code you're willing to share for Calendar, it'll be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: what is the date that you are getting from your jsp, can you give the exact value ?

Answer (score 0):

an example of using java.sql.Date

```
public class A
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        java.sql.Date jsqlD = java.sql.Date.valueOf( "2010-01-31" );    
        System.out.println(jsqlD);
    }
}
```